# CheckBox and Hidden field values not updating inside Repeater

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater, viewstate, hidden-field

I am using a TabContainer control which contains a usercontrol which is dynamically rendered depending upon selected tab. Inside usercontrol I have a repeater which contains a checkbox,label and hidden field. I am updating/changing the values of these fields inside itemdatabound event.

Everything is working fine when page loads first time but after that if I rebind the repeater then only label values are changing and checkbox/hiddenfield containing some old values.

I am not using any updatepanel at all. Please suggest what I am doing wrong.Below is my code snippet inside itemdatabound.

```
protected void rptrIngrList_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                SimpleIngredientObject currentItem = e.Item.DataItem as SimpleIngredientObject;

                HiddenField hiddenIngrId = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnIngrId");
                hiddenIngrId.Value = currentItem.IngredientId.ToString();

                HiddenField hdnAltIngrId = (HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("hdnAltIngrId");
                hdnAltIngrId.Value = currentItem.IngrAltId.ToString();

                HtmlGenericControl span = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("abcd");
                if (currentItem.UserIngrAvailability == 0 || currentItem.UserIngrAvailability == null)
                    span.InnerText = GetAvailabilityChar(currentItem.IngrAvailabilityId);
                else
                    span.InnerText = GetAvailabilityChar(currentItem.UserIngrAvailability);

                Label lblIngrName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("LabelIngredientName");
                lblIngrName.Text = currentItem.IngredientName;


                CheckBox chkIngrUse = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chkIngrUsage");
             //   chkIngrUse.Checked = (currentItem.IngrMarked == null) ? false : (currentItem.IngrMarked == true) ? true : false;
                chkIngrUse.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "IngrMarked"));

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the code where you try to save the data? It seems you are rebinding old values before you save the new form data.

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem. I am getting data in a Session variable called Session["ListIngredients"] when page load first time and after that I am putting the filtered output in another session variable called Session["SearchResult"] which is binding to repeater.

Also when I am debugging the code I can see the values inside

Answer (score 0):

Repeater will only fire  ItemDataBound when Databind() has happened - so you have to call databind() on the repeater. So your code will not fire if you have not called Databind() manually. After the datasource is available, it will go through each item and call itemdatabound event. That is why you can see the DataItem value ( which is the object from the datasource).

Comment: I am already binding repeater using DataBind() on page load of user control which contains repeater. The problem is that values assigned to hidden field and checkbox in itemdatabound are not updating on UI which are inside repeater.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with an asp:HiddenField inside an asp:repeater.
The issue was : On PostBack, the values inside my asp:Repeater where refreshed with DataBind() in the Page_Load() method instead of the ButtonSearch_click() event method. That's why I was still getting old values in asp:HiddenField and asp:CheckBox of my HTML table.